# Hiding group indicator in Expandable List view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview, expand

I want to hide the group expanded/collapsed indicator in n expandable list view in all of my list elements and instead show an image in place of the indicator. I've made the indicator color transparent using this:

```
 android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent
```

But that won't let me  place the image where the indicator used to be so I need a new way to do it.

Comment: (in Java, when you initialize your view) if elv is your ExpandableListView: `elv.setGroupIndicator(null);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement your own `BaseExpandableListAdapter`:

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    ... 

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group_item, null);
        return rowView;
    }

    ...

}
```

`list_group_item` should contain the desired group indicator image. And don't forget to disable native indication:

```
expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need set android:groupIndicator="@null"